# Error when I try insert a simple point into a geoserver point layer

Tags: javascript, xml, post, insert, geoserver

I try insert a simple point into a geoserver point layer from express to avoid cors, the commands are:

```
var config = {
      headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
      'type': 'POST',
      'dataType': 'xml',
      'processData': 'false',
    }
 };
thebody = "<Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd"><Insert><expedientes xmlns="cite"><geometry><Point xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:25830"><pos srsDimension="2">531773.0789097454 4076235.0532130245</pos></Point></geometry></expedientes></Insert></Transaction>"


axios.post(myUrl, thebody, config)
   .then(function(response) {
    console.log("Respuesta processXml : " + response.data)
       }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Respuesta error processXML : " + error)
   })
```

The error is :
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation=`"`http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 [http://app.dipalme.org:80/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd">](http://app.dipalme.org:80/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd%22%3E)
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="MissingParameterValue" locator="request">
ows:ExceptionTextCould not determine geoserver request from http request org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter$AdvancedDispatchHttpRequest@404d0d24</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>

In the forums I have been able to see that the solution was to add a header as content-type but as you can see I already include it, Could you help me, thanks.

Now, It seems that the problem is that geoserver does not understand the data sent in xml.

This is the error in log of the geoserver:

2020-10-13 11:53:27,125 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wfs] - Unable to find user-defined schema location for: http://www.opengeospatial.net/cite. Using a built schema location by default: http://app.dipalme.org:80/geoserver/cite/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typeName=cite%3Aexpedientes
2020-10-13 11:53:27,139 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2020-10-13 11:53:28,726 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /cite/wms, QueryString: service=wfs'; against '/web/**'
2020-10-13 11:53:28,726 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /cite/wms, QueryString: service=wfs'; against '/gwc/rest/web/**'
2020-10-13 11:53:28,726 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /cite/wms, QueryString: service=wfs'; against '/'
2020-10-13 11:53:28,727 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /cite/wms, QueryString: service=wfs'; against '/j_spring_security_check'
2020-10-13 11:53:28,727 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /cite/wms, QueryString: service=wfs'; against '/j_spring_security_check/'
2020-10-13 11:53:28,727 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /cite/wms, QueryString: service=wfs'; against '/j_spring_security_logout'
2020-10-13 11:53:28,727 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /cite/wms, QueryString: service=wfs'; against '/j_spring_security_logout/'
2020-10-13 11:53:28,727 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /cite/wms, QueryString: service=wfs'; against '/rest/**'
2020-10-13 11:53:28,727 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /cite/wms, QueryString: service=wfs'; against '/gwc/rest/**'
2020-10-13 11:53:28,727 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /cite/wms, QueryString: service=wfs'; against '/**'
2020-10-13 11:53:28,727 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Request matched by universal pattern '/**'
2020-10-13 11:53:28,727 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /cite/wms, QueryString: service=wfs with /**
2020-10-13 11:53:28,729 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/cite/wms]
2020-10-13 11:53:28,729 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/cite/wms]
2020-10-13 11:53:28,729 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/cite/wms]
2020-10-13 11:53:28,729 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/cite/wms]
2020-10-13 11:53:28,730 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/cite/wms]
2020-10-13 11:53:28,730 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapping [/cite/wms] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher@67c00356] and 1 interceptor
2020-10-13 11:53:28,730 DEBUG [org.vfny.geoserver.requests] - First 4 bytes of XML doc are : 0 ('�') 0 ('�') 0 ('�') 0 ('�')
2020-10-13 11:53:28,730 DEBUG [org.vfny.geoserver.requests] - Charset detection phase 1. Inferred encoding: UTF-8
2020-10-13 11:53:28,730 DEBUG [org.vfny.geoserver.requests] - Invalid(?) XML declaration: .
2020-10-13 11:53:28,730 DEBUG [org.vfny.geoserver.requests] - Charset detection phase 2. Charset in XML declaration is `null`.
2020-10-13 11:53:28,730 DEBUG [org.vfny.geoserver.requests] - Trying to create reader basing on existing charset information: `UTF-8`.
2020-10-13 11:53:28,731 INFO [org.geoserver.wfs] -
Request: getServiceInfo
2020-10-13 11:53:28,731 ERROR [org.geoserver.ows] -
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Could not determine geoserver request from http request org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter$AdvancedDispatchHttpRequest@1869bae3
at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:622)
at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:258)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:147)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:152)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: I have included an updated error log of the geoserver